# Derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=a$

Tags: functions, derivatives, notation

If given a function $y=f(x)$ and asked to compute its derivative, I would primarily try to get a function $\frac{dy}{dx}(x)$ but in this case we've written the derivative of $y$ at the point $x=a$, and I see notation such as $\frac{dy}{dx}_{x=a}$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}(a)$ can I consider this a function of $a$ or only a constant?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dy}$ is a noun, the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x.$ $\frac{d}{dx}$ is a verb, take the derivative with respect to $x$. The notation you're seeing says to evaluate that function at a point, e.g., $\frac{dy}{dx} \big |_{x=a}$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson : To say the least, I have qualms about an unqualified statement that that is a verb. If you say $2+2=4$ or $4<5$ then $\text{“$=$”}$ and $\text{“$<$”}$ are verbs. It is true that when you're 8 years old, your teacher will tell you to construe the $\text{“$+$”}$ in $2+2$ as a verb in the imperative mood; but still the expression $\text{“$2+2$”}$ is a noun. If one writes “The differential operator $d/dx$ is linear,” then $d/dx$ is a noun. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I tend to oversimplify, this is what I would tell my students when they start out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll work with a concrete instance of a question "if $y=f(x)$, find the derivative of $y$ at the point $x=a$":

> Let $y=x^2$. Find the derivative of $y$ at the point $x=2$.

$f(a)$ is (or represents) a constant, so there is no such thing as a "function of $a$", at least no more than there is a "function of $2$".

What is being sought after is the rate of change of the function $y$ at the point $x=a$: if you took a tangent line, what is its gradient?

It's worth categorising each of the notation used:

- $x=2$ uniquely identifies a co-ordinate on the graph $y=f(x)$. Though $x=2$ is a line on the Cartesian co-ordinate system, here we mean the point $(2,4)$ where that line intersects the curve.
- $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ is a function of $x$ (the rate of change of $y$ as $x$ changes)
- $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=a}=4$ is a value/constant (the gradient of $y$ at the point $x=2$), just as the number $7$ is a constant

Comment: Could I not introduce, what happens under different conditions and have $x=a$ or the derivative at $x=a$ for differing $a$?

Comment: @user1007028 this would simply be the function $\frac{dy}{dx}$, written with the variable $a$ rather than the variable $x$.

Comment: would this technically be independent of $\frac{dy}{dx}(x)$? as I'd need to specify that $a$ is a constant generally speaking but I'm interested in differing values of that constant.

Comment: because $y$ only depends on $x$ so having $y'$ as a function of $a$ seems a bit wrong for these purposes.

Comment: @user1007028 if $a$ is a "differing" variable with no fixed value, and $x=a$, then what is the difference between $x$ and $a$? There can be no difference, otherwise $x\neq a$. The value $a$ uniquely determines both the gradient and $y$, so $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a function of $a$ - equivalently, a function of $x$. If there is a difference between $x$ and $a$, then it can only be that $a$ is a constant, which is the case I evaluated in my answer.

Comment: i.e it's $x=a$ for some values of $x$ and $a$ not all $x.a$

Comment: @user1007028 your statements are not clear. If $x$ and $a$ are both variables, both independent, and $x=a$ only at "particular values of $x,a,y$" then what are the definitions of $x$ and $a$? Can you give a concrete example? $y=x^2$ and $a=...$?

Answer (score 1):

When you define a function $f(x)$ on its domain $X$, it means that for each $x_0\in X$ you know the value $f(x_0)$.

In a similar sense, the derivative of a function $f(x)$ in $X$ (if it's differentiable in $X$) is defined as $f'(a)$ for each $a\in X$, hence $f'(a)$ is a constant, but $f'(x)$ is a function on $X$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please use punctuation to be more clear.

Comment: If we define $f(x)$, and we know $f(a)$ for each a, is this not the same as knowing $f(x)$ for each $x$? Surely saying we know $f(a)$ for each $a$ is the same as defining the application $f$ to a variable $a$? How can $a$ be constant and $x$ be variable, surely they both are variable in that case? or are you just saying that the set of values if $f$ over $X$ are in that form? I do get that pretty much $a$ would be constant, but what If I wanted to have $a$ variable, e.g. for different values of what would be a constant during the actual analysis of $f(x)$?

Comment: $a$ and $x$ are just notations. We usually use $a$ for a particular value and $x$ as a variable. If you define $a$ as a variable, then of course $f(a)$ would be a function instead of a particular value.